# How to write dynamic queries indepandant to the HTML form

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with the following code i am trying t write the dynamic query which will be independent to my html form. Like i don't want to write the name a every single name of field in my query i want to make it dynamic thats why using the following the approach but the problem is right after the foreach block of code just below that

any other best way kindly guide me it'll be highly appreciated.

```
foreach(){
 }
sql.="";
problem is here this sqli like contains only the last key and values not all the keys and values
```

Results:

```
 INSERT INTO Patient(patient_cell) values (033480779)';
```

whereas i want results like this

```
 INSERT INTO   Patient(patient_name,patient_address,patient_pass,patient_cell) values (Saba,Daska,12345,033480779)';
```

HTML Form

```
<form method="post" action="Patient_data.php">
        <label>Patient name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="patient_name" placeholder="Patient name">
        <br>
        <label>Patient Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="patient_address" placeholder="Address">
        <br>
        <label>Patient's Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="patient_pass" placeholder="Password">
        <br>
        <label>Patient Cell:</label>
        <input type="text" name="patient_cell" placeholder="Enter cell    no.">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Record" name="Create">
    </form>
```

code:

```
$record['patient_name'] = $_POST['patient_name'];
$record['patient_address']=$_POST['patient_address'];
$record['patient_pass']=$_POST['patient_pass'];
$record['patient_cell']=$_POST['patient_cell'];

$dbname= new Db();

$dbname->Add($record);
```

function

```
 public function Add($record) {

   $var= $record;       
   $sql.= "INSERT INTO Patient";

    foreach ($var as $key => $value) {

         $key = "{$key},";
        var_dump($key);

       $value = "{$value},";
        var_dump($value);

    }
    $sql.="(".substr($key,0,-1).") values (".substr($value,0,-1).")";
```

Comment: What you try to do looks highly instable. Certainly you can create an array of keys and values and compile that with a few lines of code into a combination of comma separated keys and values. But I would suggest a different, more robust approach: use "object relational mapping"! That means you implement a class "patient" which defines all existing attributes of a patient. Before the insert you create an object of that class, fill the existing attribute values, maybe via the constructor, then you have a sql query implemented inside that class which known how to map attributes to columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Add($record) {

   $var= $record;       
   $sql.= "INSERT INTO Patient ([%keys%]) values ([%vals%])";

   $keys = "";
   $vals = "";

   foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($keys)) {
            $keys .= ",";
        }
        $keys .= $key;

        if (!empty($vals)) {
            $vals .= ",";
        }
        $vals .= $value;

    }

    $sql = str_replace("[%keys%]", $keys, $sql);
    $sql = str_replace("[%vals%]", $vals, $sql);

    return $sql;
}
```

Try this function
Note : if some field is string you should add single quote in that field.